How to Find the Poem Furthest from a Given Poem in a Cosine Distance Matrix in Python?
I have a cosine distance matrix called dist that represents the pairwise cosine distances between 1104 poems in my dataset. The order of rows and columns aligns with a list called all_meta0, which contains metadata (title, author, etc.) for each poem.
I need to find the poem that is furthest away from a given poem called "The Parade," which corresponds to the second row of the dist matrix (i.e., index 1, using zero-based indexing). Essentially, I want to determine which poem has the largest cosine distance from "The Parade."
Here is what I have found so far online but I'm not sure how to go about it.
Extract the second row of the dist matrix, which represents the distances between "The Parade" and all other poems.
Set the distance to itself to -1 to ignore it.
Find the index of the maximum value in the row, which corresponds to the furthest poem.
Use that index to get metadata from all_meta0.
This is where the dist variable comes from:
mds = MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=1)
pos = mds.fit_transform(dist)
dist = 1 - cosine_similarity(dtm)
dist[0:5], len(dist), len(dist[0])
pos = mds.fit_transform(dist)```


It's quite straight forward since you already have distance matrix. Some sample code as follows:
import numpy as np


distances_from_parade = dist[1]

distances_from_parade[1] = -1
furthest_poem_index = np.argmax(distances_from_parade)

furthest_poem_metadata = all_meta0[furthest_poem_index]
print(furthest_poem_metadata)

